# How to set the resolution in text consoles (troubleshoot when any `vga=...` fails)

Tags: linux, video, console, nvidia

It is a common way to set the resolution of a text consoles (that are usually available by Ctrl-Alt-F1 thru Ctrl-Alt-F6) by using a `vga=...` kernel parameter.
I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid, output of `uname -a` is:

```
Linux  2.6.32-33-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 7 21:13:52 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

To identify modes available i use the `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer` which reports:

```
02: None 00.0: 11001 VESA Framebuffer                            
  [Created at bios.464]  
  Unique ID: rdCR.R1b4duaxSqA  
  Hardware Class: framebuffer  
  Model: "NVIDIA G73 Board - p456h1  "  
  Vendor: "NVIDIA Corporation"  
  Device: "G73 Board - p456h1  "  
  SubVendor: "NVIDIA"  
  SubDevice:   
  Revision: "Chip Rev"  
  Memory Size: 256 MB  
  Memory Range: 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff (rw)  
  Mode 0x0300: 640x400 (+640), 8 bits  
  Mode 0x0301: 640x480 (+640), 8 bits  
  Mode 0x0303: 800x600 (+800), 8 bits  
  Mode 0x0305: 1024x768 (+1024), 8 bits  
  Mode 0x0307: 1280x1024 (+1280), 8 bits  
  Mode 0x030e: 320x200 (+640), 16 bits  
  Mode 0x030f: 320x200 (+1280), 24 bits  
  Mode 0x0311: 640x480 (+1280), 16 bits  
  Mode 0x0312: 640x480 (+2560), 24 bits  
  Mode 0x0314: 800x600 (+1600), 16 bits  
  Mode 0x0315: 800x600 (+3200), 24 bits  
  Mode 0x0317: 1024x768 (+2048), 16 bits  
  Mode 0x0318: 1024x768 (+4096), 24 bits  
  Mode 0x031a: 1280x1024 (+2560), 16 bits  
  Mode 0x031b: 1280x1024 (+5120), 24 bits  
  Mode 0x0330: 320x200 (+320), 8 bits  
  Mode 0x0331: 320x400 (+320), 8 bits  
  Mode 0x0332: 320x400 (+640), 16 bits  
  Mode 0x0333: 320x400 (+1280), 24 bits  
  Mode 0x0334: 320x240 (+320), 8 bits  
  Mode 0x0335: 320x240 (+640), 16 bits  
  Mode 0x0336: 320x240 (+1280), 24 bits  
  Mode 0x033d: 640x400 (+1280), 16 bits  
  Mode 0x033e: 640x400 (+2560), 24 bits  
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

It looks like many hi-res modes are available, like 0x305, 0x307, 0x317, 0x318, 0x31a, 0x31b (by the way, what does the plus-number means in the list of modes?). However, setting any of these modes in kernel option string, line `vga=0x305`, results in either pitch black text console, or screen filled by blinking color/bw dots.

What is the 'modern', 'robust' way to set up high resolution in text consoles?

Comment: setting something like "video=1024x768" in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT may help. this helped me. i found this from https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/12/msg00961.html , which i found googling "debian 10 framebuffer resolution".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Newer kernels use [KMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode-setting) by default, so you should move away from appending `vga=` to your grub line as it will conflict with the native resolution of KMS. However, it depends upon the video driver you are using: the proprietary Nvidia driver doesn't support [KMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KMS), but you can work around it.

You should be able to get full resolution in the framebuffer by editing your `/etc/default/grub` and making sure that the `GFXMODE` is set correctly, and then adding a `GFXPAYLOAD` entry like so:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1680x1050x24

# Hack to force higher framebuffer resolution
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1680x1050
```

Remember to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Comment: I've got `Driver "nvidia"` in my `xorg.conf`, so it's probably a proprietary driver. I'll experiment with `grub` anyway. By the way, how to work-around the proprietary driver?

Comment: I use the proprietary driver and the above method (on a 10.10 box) and it is fine. You could always try a nouveau driver if you wanted: http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/UbuntuPackages

Comment: Looks like GFXPAYLOAD approach worked, but only with `set gfxpayload=keep` in `grub2` configuration files.

Comment: But I still have a suspicion that my video mode is not native. I provided `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1920x1080` with `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x24`, but I still see the blurred letters in console as if I were in non-native resolution.

Comment: You could use `vbeinfo` in the Grub2 command line to see what resolutions are available and choose the closest to your monitor. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: Seems that `vbeinfo` shows the same modes as `hwinfo` did. Than, looks like the 1280x1024 is the maximum available resolution, and it is used in console. I just wonder how a built-in monitor information menu still shows 1920x1080 while it's obviously not that resolution.

Comment: Stumbled across this trying to get a larger console for my VM and wanted to add to @mbaitoff's comment. To get the `set gfxpayload=keep` into the grub2 configuration, you need to add the line `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` to your `/etc/default/grub`. (This is on Debian, and I would assume Ubuntu - YMMV on others). Had to hunt this down in the grub docs, so figured I'd share.

Comment: Question: is there a reason why my TTY is so sluggish after this? I'm using an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 and set my TTY resolution to 1366x768 (the resolution that I'm using with Xfce. The sluggishness is especially then noticable, when the screen scrolls (an ls command or scrolling up and down in nano/vim).

Comment: perfect! looking for this few days!

Comment: How would you go about this with systemd-boot? Some newer distributions, namely Pop! Os has dropped grub in favor of the leaner and faster systemd-boot for new installations (on UEFI-based systems) and without grub, setting such boot options appears to be trickier.

Comment: This odd trick doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: i run debian 10 in qemu. window is too big, if i "zoom out", font is to small. i tried 640x480, then 320x240, the ...gfxpayload... as keep and 320x240, etc, do not work. intel integrated graphic card on host.

Comment: i had grub-legacy installed by mistake. after i fixed it, this does not make it used in linux stage, only somewhere near grub stage.

Answer (score 19):

For newer Debian & Ubuntu distros using nvidia, I had to do the following:

First, edit /etc/default/grub. Change the following line:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

to this:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800 
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

replacing 1280x800 with the desired resolution.

Then:

```
echo "echo FRAMEBUFFER=y" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub
```

To simply change the font size, you can do so using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Comment: +1 for dpkg-reconfigure console-setup

Comment: This worked for me on Kubuntu 16.04 with NVidia 390 driver.

Comment: This is NOT A TYPO, echo "echo FRAMEBUFFER=y" is correct. I have checked and verified this and this will not work without the subsequent echo command written to the file. Thanks!

Comment: i run debian 10 in qemu. window is too big, if i "zoom out", font is to small. i tried 640x480, then 320x240, the ...gfxpayload... as keep and 320x240, etc, do not work. intel integrated graphic card on host.

Comment: i had grub-legacy installed by mistake. after i fixed it, i have not tried this.

Answer (score 12):

Here's your best option:

Use `sudo hwinfo --framebuffer` as described, choose a video mode you would like to see during boot in console, then add the option `vga=nnn` to the kernel boot parameters.

The only trick is that `nnn` is the video mode you selected from the list produced by `hwinfo` - **CONVERTED TO DECIMAL** !!!

If you try `vga=0xwhatever` it's not going to work.

For instance I chose video mode 0x307 (1280x1024 (+1280), 8 bits), I converted 0x307 to decimal which is 775 and then I used `vga=775` in the boot parameters of isolinux/extlinux.

You can use printf to convert hexadecimal to decimal:

`$ printf "%d\n" 0x307
775`

And I got a nice fine text in all consoles from the start.

Success!

Comment: i run debian 10 in qemu. i have same problem with hwinfo as described at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360783/how-to-get-video-mode-given-by-hwinfo-when-it-doesnt-work-and-how-to-set-login

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
(a possible solution to some of us who have done changes to config files and couldn't get the success):

I have been trying to achieve this since about six months and found zero success. All of the methods that I kept finding since then didn't work at all with my system.
Then somehow I found out that you need to..
disable the CSM (Compatibility Support Module) in System BIOS's Boot section for the methods shown in above answers to actually work.

When you have enabled the CSM in BIOS's boot section, the "EFI GOP Drive" will only show up to 1280x1024 or something (videoinfo / vbeinfo or whatever you tell to the GRUB command line), and as soon as you disable the CSM, you get the full display resolution supported by your monitor. And then you need to write all that config as shown in above answers.

Again, I am repeating, you will not get the support for full resolution if you don't disable CSM in BIOS.

---

Original(frustrated mindset):
Pardon me. This is a non conventional answer. I am only here to tell that none of the above answers are working for Debian 10.6 (Bullseye), Kernel 5.10.13.
UEFI BIOS with EFI boot, HDMI-0 via Nvdia GTX 1060 with proprietary driver, i7-5775C on Z97 motherboard.

Comment: it is better to comment those answers and mention they don't work

Comment: @FargolK you are right! I should have done that Actually, a couple of hours ago, I think I may have found the right answer for me and alike. I am going to update this.

Comment: i run debian 10 in qemu. when i try to run vbeinfo or videoinfo in grub command line, they hang.

Comment: On fedora I see `can’t find command ‘videoinfo’`, any ideas?