# Increasing Command Line Resolution Centos 6.4 VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I running CentOS 6.4 in just CLI mode.  However, I have a 1080 monitor and the resolution from the CLI interface is horrible.  Do I still have to install Guest Additions in order to increase display resolution.

Answer (score 13):

#### 2.6.X kernels

You can increase the resolution at the console like so via your `/etc/grub.conf` file. Find the `kernel ...` line pertaining to your system booting up:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 ro 
        root=/dev/mapper/vg_mungr-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=vg_mungr/lv_root 
        rd_LVM_LV=vg_mungr/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD 
        rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
        SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us 
        console=ttyS0,115200 crashkernel=auto vga=791
```

Where some of the values you can use for `vga=`:

- 791 - 1024x768, 16 bit
- 792 - 1024x768, 24 bit
- 794 - 1280x1024, 16 bit
- 795 - 1280x1024, 24 bit

#### Newer kernels (3.x)

As you move forward to newer versions of the Linux kernel that make use of [KMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode-setting) you'll need to change from using `vga=`, so you'll need to pay particular attention to what version of the kernel you're using. You can read more about it in this U&L Q&A titled: [How to set the resolution in text consoles (troubleshoot when any `vga=…` fails)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17027/how-to-set-the-resolution-in-text-consoles-troubleshoot-when-any-vga-fail).

#### References

- [How to change console resolution on Linux ( RHEL / CentOS / Fedora / etc)](http://www.vincentverhagen.nl/2008/08/03/how-to-change-console-resolution-on-linux-rhel-centos-fedora-etc/)

Comment: The link in the reference is dead.