# How to get video mode given by hwinfo when it doesn't work? And how to set login resolution?

Tags: boot, login, video, resolution, kernel-parameters

I tried to follow the suggestion at [this previous post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258490/208146):

> Use sudo hwinfo --framebuffer as described, choose a video mode you would like to see during boot in console, then add the option vga=nnn to the kernel boot parameters.
>
> The only trick is that nnn is the video mode you selected from the list produced by hwinfo - CONVERTED TO DECIMAL !!!

I have a UHD display and the text before login is tiny. Working in a pre-login terminal of any kind is nearly impossible and the login screen is not nice to use like this.

Nothing with GRUB works to solve this for me. Those settings are dropped much earlier in the boot process. I believe this would work if I could workout the correct number.

When I try to use hwinfo --framebuffer I just get a little rush of text right on the command line that does not print out to the terminal. If I use it without --framebuffer I get so much information, but this info does not seem to be there.

So, is there any other way I could get those video mode numbers or that I could calculate them from the resolution? I've tried every other way I could find so far with nothing giving the video mode numbers.

Or is there another way to set the login screen resolution?